# How Can I Fill These Squares in Turtle - Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to fill the color in these squares:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALaZV.png]

Right now the turtle only fills the corners of theses squares, not the entire square.

Here is my code:

```
import turtle
import time
import random

print ("This program draws shapes based on the number you enter in a uniform pattern.")
num_str = input("Enter the side number of the shape you want to draw: ")
if num_str.isdigit():
    squares = int(num_str)

angle = 180 - 180*(squares-2)/squares

turtle.up

x = 0 
y = 0
turtle.setpos(x,y)


numshapes = 8
for x in range(numshapes):
    turtle.color(random.random(),random.random(), random.random())
    x += 5
    y += 5
    turtle.forward(x)
    turtle.left(y)
    for i in range(squares):
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.down()
        turtle.forward(40)
        turtle.left(angle)
        turtle.forward(40)
        print (turtle.pos())
        turtle.up()
        turtle.end_fill()

time.sleep(11)
turtle.bye()
```

I've tried moving around `turtle.begin_fill()` and `end_fill()` in numerous locations with no luck… Using Python 3.2.3, thanks.

Comment: It's _really_ confusing that you've named your variable `squares` when it actually represents **number of sides**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't really used turtle, but it looks like this may be what you want to do. Correct me if I've assumed the wrong functionality for these calls:

```
turtle.begin_fill() # Begin the fill process.
turtle.down() # "Pen" down?
for i in range(squares):  # For each edge of the shape
    turtle.forward(40) # Move forward 40 units
    turtle.left(angle) # Turn ready for the next edge
turtle.up() # Pen up
turtle.end_fill() # End fill.
```

Answer (score 3):

You're drawing a series of triangles, using `begin_fill()` and `end_fill()` for each one. What you can probably do is move your calls to `begin_fill()` and `end_fill()` outside the inner loop, so you draw a full square and *then* ask for it to be filled.

Comment: Thanks, I would accept this answer but I can only accept one!

Answer (score 1):

Use fill

```
t.begin_fill()
t.color("red")
for x in range(4):
    t.fd(100)
    t.rt(90)
t.end_fill()
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with moving `begin_fill()` and `end_fill()` outside the loop, as several folks have mentioned, you've other issues with your code.  For example, this is a no-op:

```
turtle.up
```

I.e. it doesn't do anything.  (Missing parentheses.)  This test:

```
if num_str.isdigit():
```

Doesn't do much for you as there is no `else` clause to handle the error.  (I.e. when it isn't a number, the next statement simply uses the string as a number and fails.)  This calculation seems a bit too complicated:

```
angle = 180 - 180*(squares-2)/squares
```

And finally there should be a cleaner way to exit the program.  Let's address all these issues:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import random

NUMBER_SHAPES = 8

print("This program draws shapes based on the number you enter in a uniform pattern.")

num_str = ""

while not num_str.isdigit():
    num_str = input("Enter the side number of the shape you want to draw: ")

sides = int(num_str)
angle = 360 / sides

delta_distance = 0
delta_angle = 0

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

for x in range(NUMBER_SHAPES):
    turtle.color(random(), random(), random())

    turtle.penup()
    delta_distance += 5
    turtle.forward(delta_distance)
    delta_angle += 5
    turtle.left(delta_angle)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(sides):
        turtle.forward(40)
        turtle.left(angle)
        turtle.forward(40)

    turtle.end_fill()

screen.exitonclick()
```